# How to get node content of XML with Dom4j in java

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

I have a XML file like:

```
<description>
  <text>blahblah</text>
  <code>code</code>
  <text>blah</text>
</description>
```

I've navigated to the node `description`, and I want to read the full content including the `<text>` and so on.

I've used the `getText()`, but it returned empty string.
I've used the `getStringValue()`, but it filtered all `<text>`.
I've used the `asXML()`, the result is close, but the result contains `<description>` which I don't want.

Is there a method to get the XML content of a element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException {
  String xml = "<description><text>blahblah</text><code>code</code><text>blah</text></description>";
  SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
  Document doc = reader.read(new StringReader(xml));
  Element description = doc.getRootElement();
  String content = getContent(description);
  System.out.println(content);
}

private static String getContent(Element element) {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  for (Iterator<Element> i = element.elementIterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    Element e = i.next();
    builder.append(e.asXML());
  }
  return builder.toString();
}
```

Note that if the element has text content itself, this won't return the text content, only the child nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that `document` is and instance of `org.dom4j.Document`, then

```
String xPath = "description";
List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes( xPath );
for (Node node : nodes) {
 node.asXML()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using XPath: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add to the accepted answer by qwerky:

To ALSO be able to parse the contents of text only elements (ie it doesn't contain nested xml):

```
public static String getContent(Element element) {
    if (element.isTextOnly())
        return element.getText();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Element currElement = null;
    for (Iterator<Element> iterator = element.elementIterator() ; iterator.hasNext() ; /* Continue till done */) {
        currElement = iterator.next();
        sb.append(currElement.asXML());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

So I added the following at the start of the method:

```
if (element.isTextOnly())
    return element.getText();
```